# How to Query for Recent Rows in SQLITE3

Tags: sqlite, unix-timestamp

I'm using SQLite3 and trying to query for recent rows. So I'm having SQLite3 insert a unix timestamp into each row with `strftime('%s','now')`. My Table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, time);

INSERT INTO test (time) VALUES (strftime('%s','now')); --Repeated


SELECT * FROM test;
1|1516816522
2|1516816634
3|1516816646 --etc lots of rows
```

Now I want to query for only recent entries, for example, I'm trying to get all rows with a time within the last hour. I'm trying the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE time > strftime('%s','now')-60*60;
```

However, that always returns all rows regardless of the value in the `time` column. I really don't know what's going on.

Also, if I put `WHERE time > strftime('%s','now')` it'll return nothing (which is expected) but if I put `WHERE time > strftime('%s','now')-1` then it'll return everything. I don't know why.

Here's one more example:

```
sqlite> SELECT , strftime('%s','now')-1 AS window FROM test WHERE time > window;
1|1516816522|1516817482
2|1516816634|1516817482
3|1516816646|1516817482
```

It seems that SQLite3 thinks the values in the middle column are greater than the values in the right column!?

This isn't at all what I expect. Can someone please tell me what's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of `strftime()` is to *format* values, so it returns a string.

When you try to do computations with its return value, the database must convert it into a number. And numbers and strings cannot be compared directly with each other.

You must ensure that both values in a comparison have the same data type.
The best way to do this is to store numbers in the table:

```
INSERT INTO test (time)
VALUES (CAST(strftime('%s','now') AS MAKE_THIS_A_NUMBER_PLEASE));
```

(Or just declare the column type as something with [numeric affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#determination_of_column_affinity).)

Comment: Is there a better way to get the current timestamp than `strftime()`?